# JWT - What is the best way to use jsonwebtoken ? I'm lost

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt, restful-authentication

I’m learning to code for one year now. I mainly learned how to deal with a rest API (Node/Express on back-end and Vue on front-end).

I get to the point where I want to develop the ideas I have for app.

For this, I first wanted to develop the backend to have a authentification process that I could use as a boilerplate for other project I would have.

But now I’m completely lost with Jsonwebtoken and how to exactly use it in order to make something secure as well as user-friendly.

So far I understand that a rest API should be stateless (I.e. nothing should be store server-side and should therefore not have DB calls -as for sessions- to grant access to data).

In this respect, I’ve noted different strategies :

- Short-lived JWT : (+) this is very secure since you theoretically have to log in every time you want to access the server (-) very bad user experience
- Long-lived JWT : (+) user-friendly (persistent login) (-) very insecure (no way to check if JWT was stolen)
- Short-lived JWT with Long-lived Refresh Token…

That’s where I get confused…

From every articles/tutorials I’ve read, the refresh token should be linked somehow with a DB (e.g. to store the refresh token key or the blacklisted token…). I’ve also seen a tutorial that partly linked the secret key (to verify the token) with the hashed password stored in the DB. This is kind of smart since previous token will automatically be considered as invalid as of the moment the user changes his password… But this once again mean a DB call…

My point is that I’m coming to the conclusion that
(1) there’s no perfect way to handle authentification process in secure and user-friendly way…
(2) DB calls cannot be avoided to have something a bit secure...

And considering that conclusion, I definitely can’t understand the use of refresh token…

If refresh tokens required DB calls, you could get to the same result with only one main token…

You could for instance store a JWT ID in the token and in the DB… If those two id match upon validation of the token, you issue a new token with a new id that overwrites the previous one… Now if you use an old one, it will never be validated… Then, since you have called the DB to validate the token (most certainly the USER table), you could check in the sametime if, for example, the user is an admin or not (no need to store it in the JWT)… Finally, you could use the « hashed password » trick described above to enhance security…

So… What am I missing ? What is the best strategy ?

I’ll be happy to have your comments on this (or a link to a very good article - I’ve a lot of these though…)

Thank you very much for your help

PS: and I’m not even talking about how to send the token to the server (with cookie but risk of CSRF attach or with header but subject to XSS attack if token is stored client-side)… In this respect I’ve seen multiple tutorial that use JWT through cookie with cerf key stored client side as well as inside the jet => both should be send.

PS2: I hope I'm clear since I'm french-speaking native :-)

Answer (score 0):

So you have asked quite a few questions in this one question. It will be quite difficult for anyone to give a thoughtful answer here, but I shall try. Before that, full disclaimer, that I am the author of a new library called SuperTokens that I believe would provide you the best solution for session management. It's possible that you may have already read our blog: https://hackernoon.com/all-you-need-to-know-about-user-session-security-ee5245e6bdad. It's best if we can chat about this so that I can give you a full detailed explanation about everything you have asked (I would love to help out). Join our discord: https://discord.gg/zVcVeev

Now to answer your question(s):

- You should always only use short lived JWTs
- Doing a database call for authentication is not a problem, but as everything else, we try and optimise things, so doing fewer db calls, is better. If you go with JWT access tokens and Opaque Refresh tokens, then for most APIs, you do not need to do a db call. However, if you link the secret key of the JWT with the hashed password, then you would have to a db call for every API - which is OK, but I feel unnecessary since you are going to use short lived JWTs anyways (a few hours to a day max)
- You mentioned token theft - this is a tricky issue, but according to RFC 6819, you can use the concept of rotating refresh token to detect theft. Of course, actually doing so can be tricky as you have to take care of many race conditions and network failure issues - see https://hackernoon.com/the-best-way-to-securely-manage-user-sessions-91f27eeef460
- About why we need refresh tokens: Say you do not have a refresh token, then you would have just one token that you could treat as both, an access and a refresh token. You could still make it short lived (when it's an access token), and then after it expires, treat it as a refresh token - which also has some lifetime. The problem with this is that it's not very clean (point of expiring a token is that it is useless afterwards), and that you are exposing the refresh token over the network every single API call - reducing security. I know you can have HTTPS, but there are HTTPS MITM attacks as well - see the blog post, part 1.
- In terms of storage, one neat trick could be to split the access token into two - one to store in secure, httponly cookie, and one to store in localstorage. For every API call, send both to the server (cookies will be sent automatically anyways), and then the server would combine the two and go about authenticating. This would prevent both, CSRF and XSS attacks on sessions!

Now, you could either implement this whole thing on your own, or then use our library that does all these things out of the box: https://github.com/supertokens/supertokens-node-mysql-ref-jwt.

To discuss this more, or any other questions you have, join our discord server.

PS: I know I used this for advertising my lib, but I hope I did answer your question. It is genuinely difficult to give a good explanation to your questions without having a conversation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Very instructive as well as the articles. I had a look on supertokens which seems very nice. Actually, as a newbie, I want to do this myself first for learning purposes and trying to better understand what I should put in place... So far, I came to this (sill to be improved) result : https://github.com/HackinoSelov/authentification/tree/master/server
If you check it out, you'll see the (basic) logic I took with the tokens (with Refresh tokens :-)).
Feel free to comment if you have some times (but I of course understand you might not ;-)

Comment: Hi. I have partially gone through your github. I have a few questions for you so that I can give you good feedback. Please find me on Discord. My username is rp#5569. Alternatively, you can join my discord server on https://discord.gg/zVcVeev and then DM me.